# Toolbar not appearing/is swiping in older apis

Tags: android, android-menu, android-toolbar, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm having difficulty getting the support toolbar to be clickable/touchable in API's less than 20.

And by that I mean, the PageSlidingTabStrip can't be swiped and the searchView can't be instantiated (details below ofc).

I don't understand, because I implemented from the beginning a support.Toolbar. So here's the details of my implementation, which may render my toolbar not being clickable :

***The desired effect***
[image: Screenshot of the app]

***layout.xml***

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:elevation="4dp"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<com.insa.burnd.controller.PagerSlidingTabStrip ... />
```

***onCreateOptionsMenu***

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

// Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
SearchManager searchManager =
        (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(...);
searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.hint));
searchView.setSearchableInfo(
        searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

return true;
}
```

***menu_main***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="Filter"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

**Thank you !**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in your layout.
Please recheck if you have some View that is in your layout with

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

it can overlay you toolbar, and that can be the problem

change it to fixed size or another container like [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)

Comment: None of my views were hiding the toolbar layout. But the Design Library seems to have fixed the issue !